# Multiple runners in one file only yield results of the first

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, runner

I am trying to use TestCafe to automate my project's initial setup. In the middle of the setup, a POST request that takes a long time has to be made before the setup could continue. This is my `runner.js` and it's running in Node 10:

```
const longRunningPostRequest = require('./setup/seed-database');
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

const RUN_OPTIONS = {pageLoadTimeout: 120000, selectorTimeout: 15000};

const setupLicense = async () => {
  const testcafe = await createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338, undefined, true);
  const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
  const failedCount = await runner
    .src(['fixtures/setup-license.js'])
    .browsers(['chrome -incognito'])
    .run(RUN_OPTIONS);
  await testcafe.close();
};

const setupData = async () => {
  const testcafe = await createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338, undefined, true)
  const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
  await runner
    .src(['fixtures/setup-wizard.js'])
    .browsers(['chrome -incognito'])
    .run(RUN_OPTIONS);
  await testcafe.close();
};

// running them all in sequence
setupLicense()
  .then(() => longRunningPostRequest()) // long-running POST request. Typically takes around 100 seconds to complete
  .then(() => setupData())
  .catch(err => console.log('Error occured:', err));
```

When I run the application `node runner.js`, they are working. However, only the results of the fixtures in `setup-license.js` gets displayed, while the fixtures from the second runner `fixtures/setup-wizard.js` do not show any output (but they are being run and are working), but it's very annoying to work with since if it fails, the error message gets swallowed as well. The workaround I did was to comment out the content of the `setupLicense` fixture so that `setupData`'s outputs appear.

How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Could you please try to install and use `testcafe@0.23.3-alpha.2`? We've recently fixed a bug that could cause such issues - TestCafe closed the `stdout` output stream when no explicit reporter was specified. This prevents any test results to be displayed in second and consecutive test sessions starting from one script file.

As a workaround, you can enable the `spec` reporter explicitly by adding the `.reporter('spec')` call to your setup code as it is shown at: https://gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/c9afd908d4b2891a62a4ba87623ec064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the latest testcafe@0.23.3 version. The team recently fixed a bug that could cause such issues - TestCafe closed the `stdout` output stream when no explicit reporter was specified. This prevents any test results to be displayed in second and consecutive test sessions starting from one script file.

As a workaround, you can enable the [spec reporter](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-reporter-spec) explicitly by adding the [.reporter('spec') call](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/runner/reporter.html) to your setup code as it is shown in this example:

[gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/c9afd908d4b2891a62a4ba87623ec064](https://gist.github.com/AndreyBelym/c9afd908d4b2891a62a4ba87623ec064)